# Como conectar una aplicacion WPF con SQL SERVER usando un servicio web?

Tags: c#, sql-server, webservice, wpf

Tengo una aplicacion wpf con una conexion a sql server a traves de una cadena de conexion creada por entity framwework, pero necesito conectarme a sql server a traves de un servicio web ( el servicio web tiene la cadena de conexion)

Comment: Por curiosidad: ¿por qué redactaste la pregunta en inglés? ¿Llegaste desde Stack Overflow o accediste directamente a Stack Overflow en español? Nos encontramos con este caso diariamente y sería útil saber el motivo, para poder mostrar la información de manera más clara, explicitando que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en castellano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal cual planteas tu pregunta hay mucha informacion para darte. Por decirlo de una manera sencilla, un servicio web es un programa que pones en un servidor y que esta disponible a traves de internet.

Como has dicho que tienes un sql server entiendo que lo tienes en un windows server, si es así lo que tienes que hacer es activar IIS, montar el servicio web y averiguar la ruta.

Una vez hecho eso la aplicación conecta con ese servicio y recibe la información.

Investiga sobre eso y si tienes dudas mas concretas abre nuevos temas.